# Does General Onimaru's Clockwork Soldier prevent retreats?

Tags: flash-duel

General Onimaru's Clockwork Soldier ability prevents players from **moving** backwards.  Does it also prevent **retreating** from a **dashing strike**?  If a player is forced to **retreat** past the Clockwork Soldier, does the Clockwork Soldier keep advancing and if so, is the player now prevented from **moving** past it in the opposite direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes, movement is treated the same regardless of how the pawn is moved.** David Sirlin [answered](http://boardgamegeek.com/article/8075792#8075792) this question here:

> Q: Onimaru's Clockwork soldier state that the opponent cannot move behind the token. Does it also prevents any retreat? Because the way I see it, your opponent has a "wall" that moves toward him 2 case per turn, but the wording of the card implies something else.
>
> A: The movement rules are the same across the whole game. By "movement," that means "the rules for changing the position of your pawn for any reason, when it would reach an obstacle" are the same across the whole game. It doesn't matter if the "movement" is a move, push, dashing strike, retreat, etc. It doesn't matter if the obstacle is a player pawn, the edge of the board, or a clockwork soldier. In all cases, you go as far as you can, then stop when you reach the obstacle.

Comment: Gotcha.  The coloring of the word "**move**" made me wonder if it only applied to **move** as to other movements.